# print selected value in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me how to print the selected value in the same web page in JavaScript for below code please?

```
<form>
  What color do you prefer?
  <input type="radio" name="colors" id="red">Red
  <input type="radio" name="colors" id="blue">Blue
</form>
```

Comment: Print to where? The console? When should it be printed?

Comment: in the same webpage only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can `console.log` it or add it inside another element on page. The following is an example.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener("input", function(ev) {
    var value = elem.closest("label").innerText
    console.log(value)
    // or
    document.getElementById("output").innerText = value
  })
})
```

```html
<form>
  What color do you prefer?
  <label><input type="radio" name="colors" id="red">Red</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="colors" id="blue">Blue</label>
</form>

<p id="output"></p>
```